# PHP passagem de parametros

Tags: php

tenho uma tela de cadastro onde o usuário pode alterar seus dados e após clicar no botão 'Salvar alterações' as mudanças são feitas na base de dados. Segue o botão que criei na janela de edição de usuário:

```
<input type="submit" name="atualizarusuario.php?id=<? echo $usuarios->fields['id_usuario']; ?>" value="Salvar alterações">
```

Na tela 'atualizarusuario.php' quero pegar esse ID para em cima dele fazer o update e exibir, entao, nessa tela a mensagem de que a alteração foi realizada com sucesso. Estou 'pegando' o ID da seguinte maneira:

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];
```

porém, se dou um `echo $id`, não está trazendo o ID. Qual o erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode colocar a variável com o ID dentro de um input do tipo hidden e envia-lo via post.

```
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="<?php echo $usuarios->fields['id_usuario']; ?>">
```

E então na outra pagina:

```
$var = $_POST['var'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Para enviar uma parâmetro pela url(que usa o método get) esse valor deve ser colocado no atributo action da tag form e não no input submit. No exemplo o único campo enviado pelo get será o id os demais serão pelo post.

Assim:

```
<form method="post" action="gravar.php?id=<?php echo $usuarios->fields['id_usuario'];">
```

Ao enviar informações sigilosas prefira o envio por post, isso é feito com a criação de input hidden e a definição de `post` no methodo da tag form.